# swift protocol func with @escaping callback

Tags: swift, closures, protocols

I created a protocol with a function definition that has a callback function parameter.
But when I try to use the callback in a class that implements the protocol, I get the error:

*Closure use of non-escaping parameter 'callBack' may allow it to escape*

The fix adds the **@escaping** flag to the function definition, but then it's no longer confirms to the function definition in the protocol.

This is the function I pass as call back:

```
private func handleSignUpRes(result:Bool, msg:String, uData:UserData){
    if(result == false && (currVC != nil)){
        Utilities.ShowAlert(title: "Error", msg: msg, vc: currVC!)
    }
    else if(result == true){

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass in a closure that does not escape.

Escaping closures are closures that have the possibility of executing after a function returns.

Rewrite your closure to ensure that it cannot return a value after the function returns.

Unfortunately, without seeing the closure, I cannot tell you why the closure is escaping.

When you post the closure, I will edit my answer.

Comment: I added the code. There's nothing special about it.

Comment: Do you know what a closure is?

Comment: Yes, but isn't it the only way to pass a callback function?

Comment: Are you saying you are passing a function into some other function?

Comment: trying to, I want to call it once I know the result

Comment: Then you can’t use Utilities.ShowAlert because that is most likely escaping